# how to position an enlarged div in a center when hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a bit of tricky one to do.

Here's my **HTML markup**.

```
<div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="a"> 
                    <h2>Luigi's Mansion1</h2>
                    <small>08/27/2013</small>

                    <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.<br /><a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1212598-Luigi-s-Mansion" target="_blank">Artwork by Scott Balmer</a> </p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bar">
                <div class="a"> 
                    <h2>Luigi's Mansion1</h2>
                    <small>08/27/2013</small>

                    <p>Autem conventio nimis quis ad, nisl secundum sed, facilisi, vicis augue regula, ratis, autem. Neo nostrud letatio aliquam validus eum quadrum, volutpat et.<br /><a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1212598-Luigi-s-Mansion" target="_blank">Artwork by Scott Balmer</a> </p>
                </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo{
    width: 299px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar{
    margin: 0; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f0f0f0 url(images/nav_a.gif) repeat-x;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
     -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
     -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
     -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s ;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
}

.bar:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -20px;
    width: 410px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Here's the working link on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9DUN/2/).

What I'm trying to do here is that if I hover my mouse in any one of the div containers with "bar" classes, I want to see that the div bar class' dimensions gets enlarged ie its width and height.  But as their dimensions get enlarged, I want its position to still remain intact in the center of the screen.  Thus the effect I'm trying to produce is the hovered div's dimensions will grow outwardly from its center point without causing the other div underneath him to move?  Cause if you look at the JSFiddle link, other bar divs get moved and the side effect it's not right.  They should remain in their same position unless I hovered my mouse over them.

Can somebody advise is this possible to accomplish or not?  Do really I need to write javascript to handle this type of effect to work?

Let me know if you need anything else for me to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/j9DUN/4/

I only changed the margin within `.bar:hover`

```
margin: 0 -5px -20px;
```

- Top-margin: 0, as we don't want the top-position to move
- Left- and right-margin: -5px, as the div is 10px wider, equally share this
- Bottom-margin: -20px, as the dive is 20px taller (and don't want the next div to move)

Comment: Yup.  That's the idea!  I'm glad that my question somewhat makes sense... Glad you figured it out.  It's pretty close to the solution I'm looking for in building my own js plugin where if there's a list of div containers and user hovers any one of them, the hovered item will get enlarged and its dimensions will be restored as you hover other div container items.  Thanks!